# visual block copying didn't work

Tags: cut-copy-paste

I have the following lines

```
autocmd filetype tex nmap <d-p-1>       cha
autocmd filetype tex nmap <d-p-2>       sec
autocmd filetype tex nmap <d-p-3>       sub
autocmd filetype tex nmap <d-p-4>       ssub
autocmd filetype tex nmap <d-p-5>       par
autocmd filetype tex nmap <d-p-6>       subp
autocmd filetype tex nmap <d-s-p-0> part*"
autocmd filetype tex nmap <d-s-p-1>     
autocmd filetype tex nmap <d-s-p-2> 
autocmd filetype tex nmap <d-s-p-3> 
autocmd filetype tex nmap <d-s-p-4> 
autocmd filetype tex nmap <d-s-p-5> 
autocmd filetype tex nmap <d-s-p-6>
```

I selected the last words in the first 6 lines using visual-block, tried to copy and paste as block(using `p` or `P`, and it just creates lines like this:

```
    autocmd filetype tex nmap <d-p-1>       cha
    autocmd filetype tex nmap <d-p-2>       sec
    autocmd filetype tex nmap <d-p-3>       sub
    autocmd filetype tex nmap <d-p-4>       ssub
    autocmd filetype tex nmap <d-p-5>       par
    autocmd filetype tex nmap <d-p-6>       subp
    autocmd filetype tex nmap <d-s-p-0> part*"
    autocmd filetype tex nmap <d-s-p-1>     
cha
sec
sub
ssub
par
subp
    autocmd filetype tex nmap <d-s-p-2> 
    autocmd filetype tex nmap <d-s-p-3> 
    autocmd filetype tex nmap <d-s-p-4> 
    autocmd filetype tex nmap <d-s-p-5> 
    autocmd filetype tex nmap <d-s-p-6>
```

This is the state of register after copying

[image: after copying]

I am using VimR and have

```
set clipboard+=unnamed
set go+=a
set cpoptions+=y
```

Why hasn't it worked?!?

update: It behaves the same in neovim binary(I am on macos). with `-u NONE` it works as intended.

Thanks

Comment: Did you press `$` to extend the selection to the end of all lines?

Comment: of course, indeed

Comment: What column did you start on?

Comment: I went to the c in "cha". I pressed `ctrl-v` then `j` 5 times until I was on `s` of "subp". then I pressed `$` and `y`.

Comment: I pressed `p` or `P` in the end of "autocmd filetype tex nmap <d-s-p-1>"

Comment: Oh, I see. I mistakenly thought you were picking up "part*". I think the behavior you're seeing is normal. The text is all left adjusted there so same when you paste. Same happens here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97545/discussion-between-eyal-karni-and-b-layer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with your clipboard setup:

```
set clipboard+=unnamed
```

I urge you to not use system clipboard as the default clipboard in Vim, it has multiple problems, including the problem you're facing right now. It's not a unknown matter that system clipboard doesn't handle block-style-texts, it only knows lines of texts.

Another example of problems that arise with using system clipboard as the default clipboard in Vim:

If you use clipboard in a recording, and you have `set clipboard+=unnamed`, your macro wouldn't run, it will exit with an error. There are many more. When you're doing much back-and-forth between system and Vim, just do manually `:set clipboard=unnamed`, and return to normal behavior afterwards. It would save you much hassle.

Comment: Thanks. But I disagree, working with the system clipboard is efficient. I consider this a bug in vim. But I might consider removing unnamed before such actions (which I seldom do)

Comment: https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/1822

Comment: @eyalkarni, yes, it's a bug. And you can do the opposite of what I suggested, i.e. you can just use vim's clipboard when system clipboard messes up and system clipboard otherwise, if your workflow requires that. And, just for the sake of saying, I don't think using system clipboard is efficient; but that comment heavily dependent on my own workflow; and that's also not the subject of this Q/A. Anyway, I hope you get a workaround, or better yet, I hope the bug gets fixed.